# Refreshing the value of a variable in a file loaded by script

Tags: javascript

My PWA loads a js file with a script. This js file (let's call it "text.js") contains a string array in which some elements are a combination of a string and a global string varialble:

`myTextArray=['This is an ' + firstStringGlobalVariable, 'This is another string without variable', 'The third one uses another ' + thirdStringGlobalVariable', etc.]`

Now, the values of the string global varialbes (firstStringGlobalVariable, thirdStringGloablVariable, etc.) are evaluated when the script in the index.html loads 'text.js'.

When I later on change the values of the string global variables, their values in the loaded 'text.js' remain unchanged (they are hard coded when text.js is loaded).

I tried removing the script that loads the text.js, and appending it again. This does not reload the js file. The values of the string global variables remain unchanged.

Would any one have a solution for updating the values in the text.js string array when they are changed after the file is loaded?

Thanks